# reloading a div on a button click using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

after click add button in popup bootstrap modal

i want to add record in database  and reload the div on same page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#Reload").click(function(){
      $("#result").html("result reloaded successfully");
   });
});
```

[image]

after click "add question " record are inserted but how to update background page

i also want to close popup

Comment: Not able to completely understand your problem here. If you want to add something to database, then what is the code that you tried?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: You should use form action or ajax to send the data to php page and store it in database after storing it update the div.

Answer (score 0):

try using  `"$('#myModal').modal('hide');"` to hide model first then append data

```
//custom lib function
  $.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

//uses
         $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#Reload").click(function(){
                  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                  var jsonOfForm = $('formSelector').serializeObject()
                  $("#result").append("result reloaded successfully");
               });
            });
```